# I have problem to run app in ionic noodle app

Tags: moodle-mobile

i am following Moodle document

Setting up your development environment for Moodle Mobile 2 (Ionic 1)

and having error 
npx gulp watch & npx ionic-app-scripts serve -b --devapp --address=0.0.0.0 --address localhost -port 8100--livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 -- nobrowser

Using gulpfile E:\Ionic\ones\moodlemobiledirectory\gulpfile.js
Starting watch...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
 Waiting for connectivity with npm...

Comment: me too facing this issue. Please help us on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run "npm run ionic:serve" command. It will solve your problem.